# How can I optimize generating random numbers between 0 and 133300 until a defined target is reached?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;


public class FindInt{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int guess = 49;
        int trys = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        while(r.nextInt(133300) != guess){
            trys = trys + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(guess + " has been found in random after " + trys + " trys!");
    } 

}
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this, or is my usage of a while loop correct? Any additional suggestions to optimize this code would be appreciated.

Comment: Efficient in what way? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, change your condition with `r.nextInt(50)` :D

Comment: You should try another stack exchange: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we can trust `Random()` class (yes generating Random numbers can be tricky)
 to generate random numbers. 
your probability of guessing the number on every try is `1/133000`

now let's say you can only guess up to 10 numbers, then the probability of guessing that number goes up to (1/13300)*10.

Since there is always a chance of Random class returns the same number twice, then we can make the algorithm slightly more clever and refine the algorithm to say `only guess a number once`.
this will increase the probability to (1/13300)+(1/13299)+...+(1/13291)

Obviously storing the previous generated numbers can use more memory. so you have to give up memory for speeding up the process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your usage of the while loop is correct.

@EricLang you're trying to guess number49. The random function you are calling:

`public int nextInt(int n)`

Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (**inclusive**) and the specified value (**exclusive**).
In your case n is equal to 133300, if you decrease that number you increase your probability to find it sooner. If you call it with 50 instead of 133300 it's very likely to be guessed with less tries.

But all this depends on your requirements.

Comment: I said the same thing in comments as a joke, but I doubt this is what the OP means by improving efficiency...

Comment: @Mena lol. I just read it. Anyway there are no improvements possible to this algorithm, since he has to guess until the random generates that number.

Comment: n is supposed to be changeable, I don't mean efficient in finding the specified integer through random.

Comment: @EricLang the algorithm is OK, you're guessing using the Random class with the right method. The only thing you can do is decrease the n (133300). If you set it to 50, Randon.nextInt(50) will only generates numbers between 0 and 49 instead of between 0 and 133299.

Comment: The run-time of that while loop is going to be O(n) no matter what you do to it. Though the worst-case scenario is arguably that n is never found.

Comment: @Compass Yes the loop will be O(n) anyway, all we are saying is that if n is small enough it will be very likely to be found..:)

Comment: @Alboz I know, I was just mentioning that the while loop can't be simplified any further unless we can instill quantum computing into the system.